# VBA drop down list with ability to append new values

Tags: vba, excel

I have a protected workbook which has a drop-down list created using data validation manually.

I have a hidden worksheet, where I have defined names for values in it and created a data validation on the actual sheet using `=SheetName!A1:A6`.

It suffices my need. However, a new request has raised that should have the ability to add new values by the users.

For Example: Let's say I have a drop down values are A, B and C. Now the user is bound to select one among three. But going forward he should be able to add any new value if he wants to like D,E(one time use). Not necessary that values should remain in the dropdown list for future use.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a fixed list use the `offset` function to create a dynamic named range and assign the data validation to the named range. This way all the user need to do is add another item in the list and it gets updated in the data validation dropdown as well

[Here](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dynamic-named-range.html) is a link on how to do that in case you don't know how to

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't sound like you need to add them to your validation if they are only for one time use. Just allow validation to accept other values:

In Data Validation go to "Error Alert" tab and do either of the following:

1. Uncheck "Show error alert..."
2. Change "Style" to anything other than "Stop" (i.e. "Warning" like below)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You know the hidden sheet where you store the values to appear in your drop down?

1. Insert a row before row 1 and enter a value in A1 (which should be blank as you've just inserted it) that describes the list e.g ListValues
2. Then select all the data in column A (excluding blanks), press Ctrl+T, tick the box that says my data/Table has headers, click OK.
3. You should now have a 1-column Excel table. If you click the table, then click Design at the top of the screen, you can then name table using the field in the top-left of the screen.

You can then refer to your validation range as (make sure you also tell VBA what workbook and worksheet the table is located in):

```
Range("TABLENAME[COLUMNHEADER]")
```

You should replace TABLENAME with the name you gave it in step 3 and COLUMNHEADER with the name you gave it in step 2 above.

Entering new value(s) immediately below the table's last row will cause the table to extend automatically and include the newly added value(s). To remove values, you will need to delete the entire table, not just delete the value.

Hope that helps.